# What SEO considerations and/or improvements (if any) are realized when "SVCB" DNS RRs are added?

Tags: seo, domains, dns, ip-address, dns-lookup

The primary purpose of SVCB records is to decrease the time and complexity of the client lookup by providing the origin IP address directly rather than forcing the client to fetch the A/AAAA or CNAME record in cases where resources are served over a load balancer framework or from multiple endpoints designed to be equally authoritative.

Example configuration and [reference](https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/draft-ietf-dnsop-svcb-https-02.pdf)

`example.com 3600 IN HTTPS 1 example.net alpn=”h3,h2”`
`example.com 3600 IN HTTPS 2 example.org alpn=”h2”`

That being said, my question is, has there been any observation of SEO being affected, either positively or negatively, by the implementation of such records? In the event where such data either has not or cannot be quantified, do grounds for anticipating such a potential effect even exist?

Comment: "by the implementation of such records" You may be too quick. They are not a standard yet. CloudFlare and Apple did express publicly they provide/use it, but even so we are far from something being mainstream. Also purpose of those records is not unique: it is also to solve CNAME at apex problem, to enable ESNI, etc.

Comment: You make a valid point. I am actually using Cloudflare, which, as you mentioned, does offer the ability to configure SVCB records. After doing some research, however, I realized there was not much information on the subject. I agree; it may be too soon even to answer this question; still, I figured it might be worth asking in the event anyone already had personal experience to draw from.

Comment: Browser makers (Google and Mozilla AFARI) did say they will implement it (which was mostly a prerequisite because otherwise the attempt would have been doomed from the get go, as otherwise browsers would have used `SRV` records already), and the proposal gathered mostly only positive feedback so it has a high probability to become an RFC and hence "standard". However I doubt it could have much impact on SEO, or else in as much the DNS in general has. But since you use a provider having them you can already make some experiments (albeit with reduced set of clients using them)